# Disable back button in prism.windows 6.3 for UWP App

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, prism

I try disabling the soft back button in a desktop UWP App using prism, but the button always shows up after navigation using NavigationService of Prism.

How to disable the back button completely or (if not possible) on page base?

I tried this on a autowired view model:

```
    public override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigatedToEventArgs e, Dictionary<string, object> viewModelState)
    {
        base.OnNavigatedTo(e, viewModelState);
        SystemNavigationManager.GetForCurrentView().AppViewBackButtonVisibility = AppViewBackButtonVisibility.Collapsed;
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Disable back button in prism.windows 6.3 for UWP App

If you want to disable back button, you could use [`DeviceGestureService`](https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism/blob/794213ef7e06bfb82e35e3b14b0f0232262bf339/Source/Windows10/Prism.Windows/AppModel/DeviceGestureService.cs) to realize it. You could overwrite [`OnCreateDeviceGestureService`](https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism/blob/d8759f9e45e30a7c2d47c20737430fa0ccadb55a/Source/Windows10/Prism.Unity.Windows/PrismUnityApplication.cs#L131) method to get GestureService instance, and set `UseTitleBarBackButton` to be false like following.

```
protected override IDeviceGestureService OnCreateDeviceGestureService()
{
    var svc = base.OnCreateDeviceGestureService();
    svc.UseTitleBarBackButton = false;
    return svc;
}
```